# things to learn for partitioning a graph?

Tags: graph, computer-science

I am going to do a project that needs to partition a graph(most time it's a tree) to several balanced child partitions. Each node will have a weight.

Since I didn't learn much about this before and never touched this area in my ten years programming age.

Could somebody point me the things I need to learn to accomplish this project perfectly? I mean what's the shortest and key learning path?

Book/Article suggestions are also appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: cstheory.SE is for research-level TCS, which this question is probably not. It would have been perfect for the upcoming [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science-non-programming?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2), though. So, if you like to have a place for questions like this one, please go ahead and help this proposal to take off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:
http://code.google.com/p/graph-theory-algorithms-book/

Look at chapter 3. The latest download of the pdf is in the lower left corner.